# PHP JSON encode doesn't return array keys

Tags: php, json

I am having trouble with ids in an associative array not being encoded in the JSON string. I have the following PHP snippet:

```
require_once("../common/connection.php");
$hermesDB_PRST = $HERMESPDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblTX INNER JOIN tblUsers ON tblTX.SourceUserID = tblUsers.UserID WHERE TargetUserID = :TargetUserID AND TargetNotified = 0");
$hermesDB_PRST->bindValue(":TargetUserID", "2");                    
$hermesDB_PRST->execute() or die($HERMESPDO->errorInfo());
$NotificationsStack = array();
while ($hermesDB_RSLT = $hermesDB_PRST->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
    $ID = $hermesDB_RSLT["ID"];
    $Source = $hermesDB_RSLT["Source"];
    $Msg = $hermesDB_RSLT["Msg"];
    $Notification = array(
        "TXID" => $ID,
        "Source" => $Source,
        "Msg" => $Msg
    );
    $NotificationsStack[$ID] = $Notification;
}
$sRetData = array(
    "Balance" => 0,
    "Transactions" => $NotificationsStack
);
echo json_encode($sRetData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Which correctly produces the following json result:

```
{
    "Balance": 0,
    "Transactions": {
        "1": {
            "TXID": "1",
            "Source": "456",
            "Msg": "reason 1"
        },
        "3": {
            "TXID": "3",
            "Source": "456",
            "Msg": "reason 2"
        }
    }
}
```

But if I do it manually like this:

```
$NotificationsStack = array();
$ID = "0";
$Notification = array(
    "ID" => $ID,
    "Source" => "123",
    "Msg" => "haha"
);
$NotificationsStack[$ID] = $Notification;

$ID = "1";
$Notification = array(
    "ID" => $ID,
    "Source" => "456",
    "Msg" => "hehe"
);
$NotificationsStack[$ID] = $Notification;
$sRetData = array(
    "Balance" => 0,
    "Transactions" => $NotificationsStack
);

echo json_encode($sRetData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I get:

```
{
    "Balance": 0,
    "Transactions": [
        {
            "ID": "0",
            "Source": "123",
            "Msg": "haha"
        },
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "Source": "456",
            "Msg": "hehe"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I'm wondering why in the second case the IDs are not "displayed" as it would in an associative array. Instead just a list appears. This despite the fact that I enter the IDs as strings and not as integers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just because you manually set the correct automatic IDs for an array. Change the second to other number, or start from another number different to zero and you will see.

Comment: That's because at the first example you don't use sequential keys 1,3... , but the second one you used a sequential keys 0 then 1. So if you want to force the the array to be an object you can use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` instead of `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`.